# Google maps v3 data.feature Editable?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geojson

I have polygons loaded using method

```
map.data.loadGeoJson('geo.json',{ idPropertyName: 'ID' });
```

Now I want to make editable one of loaded from geojson polygons.

I was tried:

```
map.data.getFeatureById(1).setProperty('editable', true);
```

But it seems that data.feature don't have editable property?

Any ideas how to make it in easiest way?
Only one idea that I have in this moment is to make my own parser from geoJson and draw all shapes as google.maps.Polygon().

Comment: I found a solution. Maybe it isn't the best one but it solve my problem for now.

Comment: Have you tried `map.data.getFeatureById(1).setStyle({editable: true})`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe it isn't best solution but it works for me now.
I'm duplicating shape geometry from feature and creating new polygon in place.

```
var shape = [];
for (var i = 0; i < map.data.getFeatureById(ID).getGeometry().getLength(); i++) {
        var shapeData = map.data.getFeatureById(ID).getGeometry().getAt(i).getArray();
        shape.push(shapeData);
    }

    nowEditingShape = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: shape,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
    editable: true
    });
    map.data.remove(map.data.getFeatureById(ID));
    nowEditingShape.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 9):

I think this is the simplest way to do it:

```
map.data.overrideStyle(map.data.getFeatureById(1), { editable: true });
```

Comment: Nice and simple.

Answer (score 4):

Part code of this tool
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geojson/

```
  // Initialise the map.
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-holder'), {
    center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
    zoom: 3
  });
  map.data.setControls(['Point', 'LineString', 'Polygon']);
  map.data.setStyle({
    editable: true,
    draggable: true
  });
```

Full editor code: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geojson/editor.js

Answer (score -2):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(nowEditingShape, 'mouseover', function(event) {
        this.setEditable(true);
});
```

Comment: Did you read my question? Your solution doesn't set editable property for data.feature